# Hot to add ExpandableComposite to StyledText in swt

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

How can I add to StyledText, ExpandableComposite in location where i want? It is possible? Or is there similar component which can hide and show text in StyledText?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`StyledText#setCaretOffset(int)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StyledText.html#setCaretOffset%28int%29) to move the caret to the position where you want to insert and then use [`StyledText#insert(String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StyledText.html#insert%28java.lang.String%29) to insert the text. Here is an example:

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setText("This is the default text");

    Button button  = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Add random text");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            text.setCaretOffset(RANDOM.nextInt(text.getText().length()));
            text.insert("RANDOM TEXT");
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I need to have button in the same place where text should be inserted.

Comment: @JohnSmith You want to add a `Button` to the `StyledText`? If so, there is an example [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet217.java).

Comment: @JohnSmith Then have a look at the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Ahh, there is link. Thanks.